# Remove section from a Tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a switch button to hide and show a section in table view

lets say I have three section that defined in a array:

```
var sections = ["section1", "section2", "section3"]
```

and here is table view protocols for sections

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}
```

and here is the function that will be called when the switch button toggle will change:

```
@objc func switchStateDidChange(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    sections.remove(at: 1)

    // My problem is here
    tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet, with: .top)
}
```

In this function, first, I said that the number of sections in the section array will be reduced by one, then delete the section 1

but if I put 1 in IndexSet, I get this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'IndexSet'

How I can tell to `tableView.deleteSections` to remove section 1?

Comment: Have you used sections array anywhere else? show the numberofrows and cellforrow codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you do a couple of things when updating the `UITableView`.

- Make sure you have removed the data from the array that the `tableView` is using
- Make sure that when you update the array it is not refreshing the tableView, for example, you an observer or `didSet` on the array.
- Make sure you have the section available before trying to update
- Tell the tableView you are going to make updates

```swift
let removeSection = 0
if tableView.numberOfSections >= removeSection+1 {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.deleteSections([removeSection], with: .top)
    tableView.endUpdates()     
}
```

Comment: `beginUpdates/endUpdates` has no effect at all in this case.

Comment: Not ideal to be making tableView updates without them - there are a few other things to check as per my updates

Comment: `beginUpdates/endUpdates` is only useful if **multiple** `insert/delete/move` operations are performed simultaneously. It's completely pointless for a **single** operation. This is clearly described in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
tableView.deleteSections([0], with: .top)
```

change value to whatever index you need

Comment: thank you so much for your help, after add it, I got this error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a specific `IndexSet` instance from the `Int`

```
tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: 1), with: .top)
```

or use the [`init(arrayLiteral:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexset/1779813-init) method of `IndexPath` which infers an `Int` array

```
tableView.deleteSections([1], with: .top)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help, after add it, I got this error Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: What exception do you get? Out-of-range? You might need the remove the rows, too.